# Could I send a message from Dead Letter Queue back to Dead Letter Queue?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I currently have an azure function that processes message from a DLQ of a service bus.
What I want to implement is to try to process this manually, but if it doesn't succeed to forward the message back to the DLQ and based on a custom logic to do that for let's say 3 times.
I am receiving the ServiceBusReceivedMessage object but when I try to send it back to DLQ either by creating a new ServiceBusClient and receiver either by using the ServiceBusMessageActions I either get a `The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance. (MessageLockLost)`. or an InvalidException.

Is what I want to do achievable or I should create a new ServiceBusMessage and resubmit the message to the original queue instead of doing it directly to the DLQ?

This is the code that resubmits everything:

```
try
            {
                var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString"), new ServiceBusClientOptions()
                {
                    
                });
                var receiver = serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("QueueName"), new ServiceBusReceiverOptions()
                {
                    SubQueue = SubQueue.DeadLetter,
                });
                await receiver.DeadLetterMessageAsync(dlqItem, deadLetterReason: Constants.DLQReason);
                //Above method not working. Bellow neither
                //await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(dlqItem, deadLetterReason: Constants.DLQReason);

            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"MessageId: {dlqItem.MessageId}. There was an error sending the message to DLQ: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When receiving a message from a dead-letter queue, it's already dead-lettered and doesn't need to be dead-lettered again. As long as you receive the dead-lettered message in a peek-lock mode, the message will remain in the DLQ. If you receive a message in a receive-and-delete mode, it will be gone from the broker and cannot be DLQ-ed.

You need to be careful not to DDOS yourself here. If a function is configured to receive from a DLQ and cannot handle a message, it will continue receiving that message unless it's completed.

Comment: Hei @Sean thanks for your answer. How can I know in which mode is the received message? 
Also, how could I remove a message from DLQ if it’s in peek mode?

Comment: I believe the default is Peek-Lock. To remove a message, you need to complete it. That indicates to the broker the consumer is done with the message, the operation was successful, and the message can be deleted. You'd complete the message using the same receiver used to receive the message in your code snippet.

Comment: Ok, so theoretically I can try to do my manual processing and if it’s not working and I don’t complete the message it should be picked up again by the function that does the processing of the dlq, correct? 
However, I guess I should implement a retry mechanism to complete a message in case it isn’t processed in let’s say 3 retry’s. However being peek locked, I guess I can’t modify it in order to be able to check if it has been processed already, no?

Comment: When a message is abandoned, the lock is released. This is why you might want to let Functions do that part rather than your own SB receiver.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more question tho. Can I somehow read a message from DLQ in azure function without completing it? Basically I am asking if I can set autocomplete on function level or that needs to be set on the service bus?

Comment: Functions SDK uses Peek-Lock mode by default. When your function completes w/o throwing an exception, Functions will interpret that as a success and will complete the message automatically. You could leverage that to achieve exactly what you need.